# n5k-5672up netflow performance

Tags: cisco-nx-os

I want to enable Netflow on N5K-5672UP and send it to my Netflow analyzer to detect the DDoS attacks but before that, i want to know if that switch has a built-in in chipset or ASIC for Netflow or not.
If i enable Netflow during high and volumetric DDoS attacks it does not affect the switch CPU performance?

Thank you.

Comment: There is nobody to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetFlow) states that the Nexus 5600 use TCAM hardware to collect data. Some minor CPU overhead is to be expected due to NetFlow packet generation, depending on the sampling rate, but there shouldn't be more than that.

However, [Cisco's NetFlow guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5600/sw/system_management/7x/b_5600_System_Mgmt_Config_7x/b_6k_System_Mgmt_Config_7x_chapter_010011.html#concept_B27322E2A74549A599151970A18B8F93) warns that NetFlow can cause high CPU load without going into detail. I guess that's for high-ratio sampling rates...